# Parse error code 154

Tags: error-handling

I am getting parse error " The operation could not be completed. Parse error 154.

Please let me know why this is happening and what can I do to resolve this

Thanks

Comment: You might like to add a little more information than that.As it is your question is like asking a doctor to diagnose an illness based on you saying "I'm sick, cough, cough". Details such as where you are getting this error, what language you are using, what you are doing to cause the error etc. are kind of required.

Comment: When do you encounter this error? What are you trying to parse? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 3):

Parse Error 154 indicates you have too many search terms in the query.  For example, you could be doing running a query containsAll on an array of strings.

```
query.containsAll('field', ['val1','val2','val3','val4','val5','val6','val7','val8'])
```

From my experience 8 values usually hits Parse's limit, so the above would fail with error code 154.

The answer is to reduce the complexity of the query, or restructure the data and/or query.